# Local site with xdebug enabled is very slow

Tags: localhost, debug

My situation. I have local site with magento on Open Server, I'm working with Sublime Text 3. Now I'm need to use xdebug (if there is some alternative with breakpoints and ties with IDE, I'm open). The fact is, then xdebug is enabled, site is very slow. Is there any fast configuration for xdebug, to save breakpoint feature, and save the speed of work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you just want to profile, try xhprof, but any debugging system will have a massive impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks for answer. How massive should be upgrade of my PC to work with xdebug in normal temp (at least 5-10 sec for page to load)? Should I consider in expanding my RAM or CPU? Now I have 8 GB of RAM and i5-4430 3 GHz CPU. I don't need exact numbers, just as much, as you may consider will be useful.

Comment: You should only run xdebug when debugging and not on a production machine. As to how to make it go faster - that's a much more complicated question. But adding more memory or additional CPUs of the same spec is unlikely to have much impact. Beyond that.....its impossible to say what might help without a lot of measurement and analysis (see also http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/ )

Comment: Um... I think I get you in misunderstanding. I'm not installing xdebug on prod site, i'm using it for local environment.